# Set nonce to style tag by code in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, content-security-policy, webpack-style-loader, nonce

Since I want to enable Content Security Policy (CSP) with `nonce` attribute in style, so I need to set `nonce` in style dynamically by the code.

The webpack setting:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: "./dist",
  watchContentBase: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Security-Policy": "style-src 'nonce-test1'"
  }
}
```

However, the `nonce` attribute is generated by server, and will not be the same all the time, so I can not hard coded `nonce: test1` in `style-loader`.

I have found [lazy loading style](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#lazystyletag), but I have not found articles or tutorials related to set `nonce` attribute dynamically when `<style>` is loaded by code.

How to add `nonce` to `<style>` by code?

index.ts

```
import styles from './styles.lazy.css';

export class MyMainClass {
  constructor(nonce) {
    loadStyle(nonce);
  }

  private loadStyle(nonce) {

    // I need to set nonce before styles are loaded, otherwise csp error will occur.
    styles.setNonceAttribute(nonce)???

    styles.use();
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader', 
            options: {
              injectType: 'lazyStyleTag', 
              attributes: {
                nonce: "initialNonce"
              }
            } 
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

On the next page of webpack - [There are two ways to work with nonce](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#nonce):

- using the attributes option
- using the **webpack_nonce** variable
  and examples of code.

Or it doesn't work in your case?

Comment: If I created `create-nonce.js` with `__webpack_nonce__ = 'initialNonce';`, I don't know how to change `webpack_nonce` in the `index.js`. It always shows `can not create property...`

Comment: hard-coded nonce(and comments below): https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/559#issuecomment-359274297; How to set Webpack interpolate the nonce expression at runtime instead of build time; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639625/how-do-i-integrate-the-value-of-webpack-nonce-with-my-content-security-poli

Comment: The methods in two links used back-end to generate `index.html` and insert `nonce` in it. My current work is to build a script (e.g. `MyJS.js`) to create some components that can be used in the website. So the `<style>` generated by `MyJS.js` needs to be inserted `nonce`. However, the website (e.g. `user.com`) that used `MyJS.js` might uses something like `<script nonce="test1" src="./MyJS"></script>`. Therefore, I need to insert `nonce` not from back-end but from the script .